# How to login with different site collections home page?

Tags: sharepoint-server, site-collection, 2016

I created different Site collections under one web application.

I was trying to login to different site collection but it was redirecting to the top level site.

Sitecollection url :

http://sharepointsite/sites/Sitecol1/_layouts/15/closeconnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true

Using the above url if i was to login it would redirect me to

http://sharepointsite/default.aspx.

How can I login to different site collection and what we want:

1. Top level site collection contains our deployed solutions (web application). So would it reflect to all other site collections ?
2. In the site collection url for the layout page; if we add any items, will it be added to the Top level list? It should be saved to the top level site collection list.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using is unsupported and should not be used as it doesn't properly clean the previous user's session. Instead, run your browser as a different user. In Windows you can shift-right click the browser to select 'Run as a different user'.